# how to store constants in mysql

Tags: mysql, constants, store

I need to store some constants in mysql in order to avoid doing subqueries or queries very complicated.

I wonder which would be the best way to do it.

```
-----------------------------------
ID      name                value
-----------------------------------
1      constant_name_1        100
2      constant_name_2          0  
3      constant_name_3         12
4      constant_name_4        257
-----------------------------------
```

I'm not sure if the example written above would be the best way because I've some doubts about it.

1) I don't need the ID field at all. I just need the constant_name, so I don't know if it's neccessary.
2) In most cases, I'll need to know the values of several constants at once, not just one. In this cases I'm not sure how should I do the queries.

"SELECT value FROM constants_table WHERE name IN ('constant_name1','constant_name2','constant_name3',...)" ??

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is reasonable. As long as the `name` will be unique I'd drop the `ID` column (there's no need for it) and make the `name` column your PK.

As for querying, my preference would be to pick the values one at a time, as needed, using a subquery. It's the "prettiest" way I can think of offhand, and it's optimizable:

```
SELECT myTable.ID, myTable.Name
FROM myTable
INNER JOIN (SELECT value FROM constants_table WHERE name = 'constant_name_1') C1
   ON myTable.ThisValue = C1.value
INNER JOIN (SELECT value FROM constants_table WHERE name = 'constant_name_4') C4
   ON myTable.ThatValue = C4.value
```